# How can I login with cookies Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I am using Deployd on a custom server for user authentication and would like to hide the 'Login Screen' (LoginViewController) if the user is already logged in and has an active session.

This is how I am making login:

```
let credential = NSURLCredential(user: "username", password: "password", persistence: .ForSession)
    let parameters = ["username" : "username", "password" : "password"]
    Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com:2403/users/login", parameters: parameters)
        .authenticate(usingCredential: credential)
        .response { request, response, _, error in

            if response!.statusCode == 200 {
                self.showCookies() //----------- Saving Cookies 
            } else {
                print("invalid credential bro!")
            }
    }
```

and this is how I'm saving cookies after making successful login

```
func showCookies() {

    let cookieStorage = NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage()
    //println("policy: \(cookieStorage.cookieAcceptPolicy.rawValue)")

    let cookies = cookieStorage.cookies! as [NSHTTPCookie]
    print("Cookies.count: \(cookies.count)")
    for cookie in cookies {
        var cookieProperties = [String: AnyObject]()

        cookieProperties[NSHTTPCookieName] = cookie.name
        cookieProperties[NSHTTPCookieValue] = cookie.value
        cookieProperties[NSHTTPCookieDomain] = cookie.domain
        cookieProperties[NSHTTPCookiePath] = cookie.path
        cookieProperties[NSHTTPCookieVersion] = NSNumber(integer: cookie.version)
        cookieProperties[NSHTTPCookieExpires] = cookie.expiresDate
        cookieProperties[NSHTTPCookieSecure] = cookie.secure

        // Setting a Cookie
        if let newCookie = NSHTTPCookie(properties: cookieProperties) {
            // Made a copy of cookie (cookie can't be set)
            print("Newcookie: \(newCookie)")
            NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage().setCookie(newCookie)
        }
        print("ORGcookie: \(cookie)")
    }
}
```

I would like to hide the 'Login controller screen' if the user is already logged in and has an active session.

Answer (score 0):

1. Assign a Storyboard ID to the ViewController you want to show when the cookies are configured correctly

[image: Storyboard ID]

2.In you app delegate verify if the cookies are configured correctly and skip the login and show the Home View Controller

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool { 
     //IMPORTANT don't forget to create a method that check if the cookies are configured
     let cookiesAreConfigured = methodThatChecksIfTheCookiesAreConfigured()
     if cookiesAreConfigured == true {
         let mainStoryboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
         let initialViewController : UIViewController = mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeVC") as HomeVC
         self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
         self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
         self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
     }
     return true
}
```